# Civicontribute registration module with wordpress

Tags: civicontribute

i created a contribution page, but when an user fills out the fields and pays we receive the paypal advice only without the user data registration. How to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have enabled receipting in the Event configuration - and double check the to and bcc fields!

Reference: https://book.civicrm.org/user/current/events/creating-an-event/

Scroll down (lots) to Confirmation Email section.

If that's working: check that you can send Email from CiviCRM: go into your Administer -> System Settings -> Outbound Email -> and try send yourself a test Email;

Reference -> https://book.civicrm.org/user/current/advanced-configuration/email-system-configuration/

Comment: The receipt is already enable and i put the email on the to and cc fields

Comment: Excellent. Ok next step is to check the outgoing Email pathway (I've amended my answer above).

Comment: The receipt is already enable and i put the email on the to and cc fields, but nothing happens. When an user make a donation civicrm send the payment receipt to the user and anything else. I need to receive the user registration data name, address, birth date and so on for internal use.

Comment: Hi Andrea - have you confirmed that you're all set up/configured to send out email from your CiviCRM? (see the bit I added to my answer above)